# ASP.NET Timer in ASCX Control embedded in ASPX Page Postback

Tags: asp.net, timer

I have an ASCX-Control which indecates an Timer, a Label and an updatepanel.
My Timer is not in the Updatepanel.
Every 5 seconds the timer is ticking and read data out of mysql-DB to count the number of new messages and write the number in an label.

In my ASPX Page I embedded the ASCX-Control. The Control is outside of an updatepanel in my ASPX-Page. When the timer in the ASCX-Control is Ticking, the Page is doing an Postback. The problem is, we lose the focus of the current control.

Heres the ASCX-Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="badgeIcon.ascx.vb" Inherits="Test.badgeIcon" %>
    <link href="css/badgeIcon.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMsg" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divIconMsg" runat="server">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="iconMsg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/iconErinnerung.svg"></asp:ImageButton>
                <div id="divMsgCount" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:Literal ID="cntMsg" runat="server" Text='0' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>   
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Timer ID="tiTimer" runat="server" Interval="5000"></asp:Timer>
```

ASPX-Page indicates ASCX-Control:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSuche" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="suche"  runat="server">
            <div id="divImgSuche" runat="server">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSuche" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/IconSuche.svg"></asp:ImageButton>
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbSuche" runat="server" placeholder="Suche"></asp:TextBox>
            <div id="divImgSucheClear" runat="server">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSucheClear" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/btnclose.svg"></asp:ImageButton>
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>   
</asp:UpdatePanel>
// ASCX-Control with Timer
<uc1:badgeIcon runat="server" id="badgeIcon" />
```

tbSuche in ASPX-Page loses the focus.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: It would be easier and faster to request the new messages with an ajax calls. This will make your site much faster and you won't have the focus problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can you show me some code how to do this with ajax?

Thanks.

Comment: Start with the basics: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp